# 301 Redirect to another domain on 1 page with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I checked other topics but didnt find my answer so here I am. First of all, my website is on Wordpress and I want to do that 301 via .htaccess.

What I would like is to redirect 3 differents pages to 3 news pages on the new domain and on the other hand redirect all the remaining pages of the old domain to the homepage of the new one.

So it would be like :

- www.old-domain.com/page-1/ -> www.new-domain.com/page-1/
- www.old-domain.com/page-2/ -> www.new-domain.com/page-2/
- www.old-domain.com/page-3/ -> www.new-domain.com/page-3/

**AND**

- www.old-domain.com/all-other-pages/ -> www.new-domain.com

So I know how to redirect to a specific page with :

```
Redirect 301 /old-url/ new-url/
```

And to redirect all the website to one url :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The main thing is that I dont know **how to mix the 2 part**s to create the condition I previously explained.

I tried to just do that so the 2nd condition would overrite the 1st one but it still redirect all pages :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/ [R=301,L]
 Redirect 301 /old-url/ new-url/
```

Any help would be lovely,
Regards,

Update :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(http://www.codepromo-live.com/voyage/economisez-quelques-euros-sur-vos-reservations-chez-pierre-et-vacances/)?$ http://www.cafaitquoi.fr/code-promo-the-north-face/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cafaitquoi.fr/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have specific rules before generic rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?codepromo-live\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(voyage/economisez-quelques-euros-sur-vos-reservations-chez-pierre-et-vacances/)?$ http://www.cafaitquoi.fr/code-promo-the-north-face/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?codepromo-live\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.cafaitquoi.fr/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey @anubhava thanks for your help ! Did try your method in different ways but still doesnt work :(

RewriteRule ^(http://www.codepromo-live.com/voyage/economisez-quelques-euros-sur-vos-reservations-chez-pierre-et-vacances/)?$ http://www.cafaitquoi.fr/code-promo-the-north-face/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cafaitquoi.fr/ [R=301,L]
Kinda stuc

Comment: Can you edit the question with your latest .htaccess so that I can understand better and help you.

Comment: You cannot use `http://host/` in your `RewriteRule`. Check my updated answer for suggested rules.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but it doesnt work either. It does redirect the all domain to cafaitquoi/code-promo-the-north-face and the specific page is redirected to http://www.cafaitquoi.fr/code-promo-the-north-face/voyage/economisez-quelques-euros-sur-vos-reservations-chez-pierre-et-vacances/ which create a 404.

Comment: That is absolutely not possible because `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?codepromo-live\.com$ [NC]` condition which will **only allow `codepromo-live.com` (www and non-www) to be redirected. What is URL you entered and what it got redirected to?